# PostgreSQL Fetch each message and all it's replies before moving to next message

Tags: postgresql

I have a `messages` table with values like below:

A value in the `replyto` field means that message is a reply to another with that `id`.

| id | message | fromuser | touser | replyto | delete | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | msg1 | user1 | user2 | 1 | 0 | t1 |
| 2 | msg2 | user2 | user1 | 2 | 0 | t2 |
| 3 | msg3 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t3 |
| 4 | msg4 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t4 |
| 5 | msg5 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t5 |
| 6 | msg6 | user1 | user2 | 2 | 0 | t6 |
| 7 | msg7 | user2 | user1 | 7 | 0 | t7 |
| 8 | msg8 | user2 | user1 | 7 | 0 | t8 |

I want to fetch and display all a user's messages while displaying each message and all it's replies as found in `replyto` before I display the next message.

The messages must be displayed in descending order and must fetch the sender's details from the `users` table.

For example the fetched results for `user1` messages should look like below (not including sender profile details):

| id | message | fromuser | touser | replyto | delete | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | msg8 | user2 | user1 | 7 | 0 | t8 |
| 7 | msg7 | user2 | user1 | 7 | 0 | t7 |
| 5 | msg5 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t5 |
| 4 | msg4 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t4 |
| 3 | msg3 | user2 | user1 | 1 | 0 | t3 |
| 1 | msg1 | user1 | user2 | 1 | 0 | t1 |
| 2 | msg2 | user2 | user1 | 2 | 0 | t2 |

The SQL query below currently works but does not fetch each message and it's replies before the next message is displayed.

```sql
SELECT messages.*, users.name AS name, users.photo AS pic, users.username AS username FROM messages LEFT JOIN users ON messages.fromuser::integer=users.id::integer WHERE messages.delete = '0' ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

The PgSQL tables:

users Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  photo varchar(255) NULL,
  username varchar(255) NULL
);
```

Messages Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  message varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  fromuser varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  touser varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  replyto varchar(255) NULL,
  delete varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  time varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Could you help me refine the sql query so that it fetches each message and all it's replies before moving on to the next message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a recursive query that starts with the rows that are no replies to anything and use the `SEARCH DEPTH FIRST` for the result row order.

Comment: If you need to get all the messages and its reply's together then you can change the order by to "ORDER BY replyto DESC, messages.id DESC", isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To refine the sql query so that it fetches each message and all it's replies before moving on to the next message we can use a recursive sql query to solve it and it can be done as follows:

This query will fetch each message and all its replies before moving on to the next message.

```
SQL
WITH RECURSIVE messages_and_replies (id, message, from_user, to_user, reply_to) AS (
  SELECT id, message, from_user, to_user, reply_to
  FROM messages
  WHERE from_user = 'user1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.id, m.message, m.from_user, m.to_user, m.reply_to
  FROM messages m
  JOIN messages_and_replies mr ON m.reply_to = mr.id
)
SELECT messages_and_replies.*
FROM messages_and_replies
ORDER BY messages_and_replies.id DESC;
```